# Calculating a probability of a function of a random variable in a limit

Tags: machine-learning, probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics

I am reading the paper [Luo et al.: Parameterized Explainer for Graph Neural Network](https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.04573) and trying to understand the mathematical reasoning after Equation (4) on page 5:
[image]

How do they calculate $\operatorname{lim}_{\tau\to0}P(\hat e_{ij}=1)$?

I tried to rewrite (4) as
$$\hat e_{ij} = \frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{\epsilon}{1+  \epsilon}\operatorname{exp}(w_{ij}) \right) ^{-1/\tau}}$$ but we have $$\operatorname{lim}_{\tau \to \infty} x^{-1/\tau}=1$$ which would imply $$\operatorname{lim}_{\tau\to0}P(\hat e_{ij}=1)=0$$